# What is the meaning of the function $f:B\to A$ for sets $A$ and $B$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Consider $A=\{1,2,3,4,5\} \text{and}$ $B=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$. then what is the meaning of the function $f:B\to A$ ?

Does that mean it is a function which its domain should contain **All** the elements of set $B$ and its range should contain **All** the elements of set $A$?

Can $f$ be the function with following values?

$$f(2)=1, f(4)=2,f(5)=3,f(9)=4,f(10)=5$$
Or we should use all elements of both $A$ and $B$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to have all elements of $B$ in the domain. If all elements of $A$ are in the range, then it'll be called a *surjective* function.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer I got it.

Answer (score 0):

The general convention I am most familiar with is that a function $f:A\to B$ is usually understood to be defined for all elements of $A$ but does not necessarily map to all elements of $B$. That is, for such an $f$, $f(a)$ will be defined for all $a\in A$, but there may exist some (or many) $b\in B$ for which there exist no $a\in A$ with $f(a)=b$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer I got it.